Flutter Firebase: Missing google_app_id
Recently I have added firebase to my flutter project. I used the dart, flutter fire and firebase CLI to initialize the project by following the steps below.
$ dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
$ flutterfire configure --project=<my project ID>

then added the firebase packages by running
$ flutter pub add firebase_core
$ flutter pub add firebase_analytics

In my main.dart I have initilaized firebase as follows
void main()  async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
}

To test if everything was working fine I added the a log in my MyApp() as follows
...
static FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
...
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    analytics.logAppOpen();

When I run my app i get the following error in my console
Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. See https:...

I have tried adding the plugins manualy in my settings.gradel as follows
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.23" apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.1' apply false

}

my app/build.gradel
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
...
flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}


I have also checked my google-services.json for app-id and it is present.
"client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "X:XXXXXXXXX:android:XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "XXX.XXXXXXXX.XXXXXX"
        }
      },

I have also tried the steps mentioned in
Github
and
stackoverflow

I was able to solve the problem by adding
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx") in my app/build.gradel
(Added it based on Flutter Firebase setup & Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled)
When I re run the application, the error went away and I was able to see the analytics event after few hours.
Here is code for reference
app/build.gradel
flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics")    //Firebase Crashlystic
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")

}

gradel.settings
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.23" apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics" version "2.8.1" apply false

}

include ":app"



If you are using flavors, I had the same issue and the solution for me was to move the google-services.json to /app/flavor/ instead of app/
